# Cylinder sets on $C[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

Suppose $\mathscr{B}$ is the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$. Let $C:=C[0,1]$ and $\mathscr{A}:=\{B\cap C: B\in\mathscr{B}$. I am trying to show that
$$ A:=\{f\in C[0,1]: \int_{[0,1]} f<1\}$$
is inside $\mathscr{A}$. We know that $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra but apart from this we have nothing. We need to construct the cylinder set $B$ such that $A=B\cap C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$B := \bigcup_{k \ge 1} \bigcap_{N \ge 1}\bigcup_{n \ge N} \bigcup_{\substack{\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_{n-1} \in \mathbb{Q} \\ \frac{1}{n}(\alpha_0+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}) \le 1-\frac{1}{k}}} \left\{f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \hspace{1mm} | \hspace{1mm} \left|f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)-\alpha_j\right| \le \frac{1}{2k} \hspace{2mm} \forall \hspace{1mm} 0 \le j \le n-1\right\}$$

Comment: Okay, so I see that $B$ is the set of all functions with integral 1. However I do not see why $B_{n,k}$ is a cylinder set in $R^{[0,1]}$.

Comment: @user593295 I hope you mean "with integral strictly less than $1$". See the updated answer

Comment: Yes less than 1** as required by definition of A.

Comment: @user593295 do you understand the updated answer?

Comment: yes I think so, so the reason why this is a cylinder is because f is specified by at most countably many points right?

Comment: @user593295 Each of these $\left\{f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} | f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right) = \alpha_j \hspace{2mm} \forall \hspace{1mm} 0 \le j \le n-1\right\}$ is a cylinder set, since it specifies $f$ at finitely many points (countably many points would also be fine). Then we take unions and intersections, which obviously keeps everything in the same $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: where do you use $N$ here?

Comment: @user593295 idk what that means. Do you mean to say "when proving $A = B \cap C$, how does $N$ enter the picture"?

Comment: yeah but I get it now, it's basically just convergence of the Riemann sum right?

Comment: @user593295 yea

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

1. Recall (or show) that $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the uniform topology on $C[0,1]$.
2. Show that the set $A$ is open in $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$. Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra contains all open sets, this implies, by Step 1, that $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Part 2 is easy, but I do not understand part 1? the construction of the Borel cylindrical algebra is independent of a specified topology? Can I see a proof of this/

Comment: @user593295 The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ equals the Borel $\sigma$-algebra associated with the uniform norm on $C[0,1]$. To prove this, a) show that the projections $\pi_t: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, f \mapsto f(t)$ are (Lipschitz)continuous, implying Borel measurabolity. b) Prove that the open balls $\{g \in C[0,1]; \|f-g\|_{\infty}<r\}$ are in $\mathcal{A}$ (use the continuity of $f,g$ to write $\|f-g\|_{\infty} = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)|$)

Comment: @saz how's the vacation?